# How can I add links into this angular demo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

so i've been playing with this angular demo and have created a codepen for it.

http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/JoBYxX

I am trying to make each of the list/grid items shown in the bottom sheet into links. Essentially, I would like to wrap them in  tags.

I have the html being pulled in through the javascript just for a working version on codepen. 
I see that it uses Ng-repeat to cycle through the items in the scope for the full amount. How can I turn each of these into their own separate links?

I'm sure it's an easy solution but I am stumped.

Thanks for the help guys

```
<md-bottom-sheet class="md-grid">
  <md-list>
    <md-item ng-repeat="item in items">
      <md-button class="md-grid-item-content" aria-label="{{item.name}}" ng-click="listItemClick($index)">
        <div class="md-icon-container">
          <md-inline-grid-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></md-inline-grid-icon>
        </div>
        <p class="md-grid-text"> {{ item.name }} </p>
      </md-button>
    </md-item>
  </md-list>
</md-bottom-sheet>
```

Angular

```
angular.module('bottomSheetDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $timeout, $mdBottomSheet){
  $scope.alert = '';

  $scope.showGridBottomSheet = function($event) {
    $scope.alert = '';  
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      template: gridTemplate,
      controller: 'GridBottomSheetCtrl',
      targetEvent: $event
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
})

.controller('GridBottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout' },
    { name: 'Mail', icon: 'mail' },
    { name: 'Message', icon: 'message' },
    { name: 'Copy', icon: 'copy' },
    { name: 'Facebook', icon: 'facebook' },
    { name: 'Twitter', icon: 'twitter' },
  ];
  $scope.listItemClick = function($index) {
    var clickedItem = $scope.items[$index];
    $mdBottomSheet.hide(clickedItem);
  };
});
```

**EDIT***
Forgot to add that I am trying to use images instead of the icons but simply putting in a url link in the codepen doesn't display it either.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, rather than the buttons doing what they do now (they each call the same function and pass in their index when clicked) you would instead like the buttons to be anchor tags with a "href" attribute of your choosing. Is that right?

If so, you have a number of options available to you.
I won't get into the ngRoute option because it's a bit more indepth, but if your links are going to point to another part of your angular app, you'll need to look into that. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

The easiest way is to assign the URL to each of the "item" objects.

```
{ name: 'Hangout', icon: 'hangout', urlPath: 'boobs.html' },
```

---

```
<a class="md-grid-item-content" aria-label="{{item.name}}" 
  ng-href="www.whatever.com/{{item.urlPath}}">
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot hank, one issues.... boobs.html doesn;t seem to be working? I really wanted to go there, but I can't seem to get it, it sounds enticing..
Jokes aside, thanks for the help, i've got it all working, any ideas on how I can include the icons from my images folder?

Comment: You're welcome.
Add this property (ng-class) here:
<md-inline-grid-icon icon="{{item.icon}}" ng-class="{{item.icon}}"></md-inline-grid-icon>

Then use that to put your image in using css.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a "source" and a "url" to your items.

```
 { name: 'Hangout', imagesource: 'Path/To/My/Image/Here', linkurl: 'Url/Here' },
```

Then wrap an image tag with an angular source directive in a hyperlink tag.

```
<div class="md-image-container">
    <a href='{{ item.linkurl }}'>
         <img ng-src="{{ item.imagesource }}"/>
    </a>
</div>
```